# Why is the Lebesgue integral of $\frac{x}{1 + x^2}$ undefined

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, cauchy-principal-value

Related to [Cauchy-random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) why is the Lebesgue-integral of the above (expectation) of such r.v not defined?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{x}{\pi(1 + x^2)} = ?$$

It seems to me that in the construction of the step functions, I want to argue by symmetry of a factor of $-1$ that this is $0$. But, the expectation is undefined which I can see when evaluating the Riemann integral as I know how. However, I do not have any measure theory background and am confused by the question of the Lebesgue integrability of such a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is in $L^1$ if both the positive part and the negative part of the function, $f_-=\max\{-f,0\}$ and $f_+=\max\{f,0\}$ (both are positive) have a finite integral. Then you define
$$
\int f\,d\mu=\int f_+\,d\mu-\int f_-\,d\mu
$$
which is well-defined (finite). In your case, both of these are infinite, so your distribution does not have a first moment (expected value).

Comment: It's worth noting that when $\int f_+d\mu=\infty$ and $\int f_-d\mu<\infty$, then the integral of $f$ **is** defined to be $+\infty$. So you do not need both of those to be finite for the integral to be defined.

Comment: Not for the integral to be defined but certainly to be an element of $L^1$. I added the word "finite" to my answer. Thanks for making the point!